# How to migrate a domain name from one Azure environment to another

Tags: azure, dns, migrate

In a MS Azure environment, let's just call it "Azure01", there is a domain name "dikketinus.nl" verified under Azure Active Directory --> Custom Domain names.

This domain name "dikketinus.nl" needs to be verified in a different MS Azure environment called "Azure02", I am aware that a domain name can only be present (verified) in one MS Azure environment at once.

To get this transition done, do I just need to:

1) remove all the resources (users, apps etc) referencing to domain name "dikketinus.nl"

2) Delete the domain name "dikketinus.nl" (after making the default domain name primary)

3) Add (and verify) the domain name "dikketinus.nl" in the other MS Azure environment

Or am I still missing something?

I am just requesting some information before putting it into practice.

There's no code involved

I think the above steps might do the trick but I am not a 100% sure...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the above steps could do the trick. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/domains-manage#delete-a-custom-domain-name) is the official document mentioned that you can remove a custom domain name from your Azure AD if you need to use that domain name with another Azure AD.

> To delete a custom domain name, you must first ensure that no
>   resources in your directory rely on the domain name. You can't delete
>   a domain name from your directory if:
>
> - Any user has a user name, email address, or proxy address that includes the domain name.
> - Any group has an email address or proxy address that includes the domain name.
> - Any application in your Azure AD has an app ID URI that includes the domain name. You must change or delete any such resource in your
>     Azure AD directory before you can delete the custom domain name.

Comment: Hi Nancy, first of all thanks for the quick response. I am aware of the article you are refering to, nevertheless your confirmation is encouraging. Within a few weeks I will put the above solution to the test and leave a final comment on the matter.